# Hyper-V guest custom resolution

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm running Hyper-V on Server 2008 R2, and the guest OSs are windows XP.
My XP VMs are currently limited to the following basic resolutions:
* 1600x1200
* 1280x1024
* 1152x864
* 1024x768

Is there a way I can get it to do custom resolutions like I can with VMWare, like 1600x800 or 1280x1280?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO. It is not possible to run a hyper-v vm in a custom resolution unless you do so via RDP.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the resolution when you view the VM just via Hyper-V Manager, this is a common complaint from developers who run a ton of PCs local to test stuff. The usual response is to use RDP which doesn't have the same resolution limitations.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do it without RDP, or do you think I would be better off switching to a non-MS solution?  RDP is not practical because I have multiple VMs that need to run 24/7, whether or not a human user is connected...

Comment: With Hyper-V, that's the only option I'm aware of. I don't know if you'll get better resolution from vmware or another platform. Not clear about your second sentence, though. The VMs can run 24/7 - you just connect via RDP when you need to and disconnect when you don't.